# Is it possible to make ServiceNow REST calls using SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am using ServiceNow REST API calls to get ServiceNow records inside my application. My application takes username,password and domain url of their servicenow account from the user to do this. I have this situation where one of my client uses OneIdentity SSO for their servicenow application. How can I make REST calls in that case?

I should be asking them to provide a local account credentials instead of SSO credentials or is there anyway I can bypass the REST calls with SSO ? If so how ?

Comment: Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I should be asking them to provide a local account credentials instead
>   of SSO credentials

Yes, web services are not authenticated in the normal way people use to log in to the system, all of them are using the basic HTTP authentication (even if you are using the SSO URL to call the web service)

References: Service now community URLs [[1]](https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=a34f4fe1dbdcdbc01dcaf3231f961931) [[2]](https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=10a5cbeddbd8dbc01dcaf3231f96198e) & My tests using Postman :)